# Error in trying to Save a tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-serving

I am  testing a simple model with the main to serving it . I am in colab environment.
executing the code

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
model=tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1,input_shape=[1])])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
xs=np.array([-1.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0],dtype=float)
ys=np.array([-3.0,-1.0,1.0,3.0,5.0,7.0],dtype=float)
model.fit(xs,ys,epochs=500,verbose=2)

tf.saved_model.simple_save(
    keras.backend.get_session(),
    export_path,
    inputs={'input_image': model.input},
    outputs={t.name:t for t in model.outputs})
```

I obtain the following error that I don't know how to fix:

````
<ipython-input-19-634675006b49> in <module>()
----> 1 tf.saved_model.simple_save(
      2     keras.backend.get_session(),
      3     export_path,
      4     inputs={'input_image': model.input},
      5     outputs={t.name:t for t in model.outputs})

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.saved_model' has no attribute 'simple_save'```
````

Answer (score 2):

`simple_save` is deprecated in tensorflow v2 ([LINK](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/saved_model/simple_save)).

Try to use `model.save(saving/path)` instead

full documentation on model.save : https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_the_entire_model

Comment: Yes it is correct, many thanks! The only doubt now, is that saved_model.simple_save has the following arguments ( session, export_dir, inputs, outputs, legacy_init_op=None)      How can accommodate inputs and outputs in simple_save?